Specify PV when creating volume in libvirt logical pool
I created a libvirt logical pool that uses an existing vg (that has a bunch of PVs with various sizes/speeds):
virsh pool-define-as --name existingvg --type logical

When I create a volume in this pool:
virsh vol-create-as --pool existingvg --name vol01 --capacty 1G

Can I choose which PV is used, or will I need to use pvmove once the volume has been created?

to not require time-consuming and load-consuming pvmove you can change allocation policy prior creation of the volume and restore it back after

Thanks, I can see how that would work, but it feels yucky - changing global state and all that.
